# How to Fix Issue: Printer Will Not Print, Gets Stuck at 40%?

Tags: macos, printing

I have a user who came across this issue recently with their hp officejet 8620 printer. The Printer will not print. No matter what we seem to try on the Mac it will not print.

When printing is tested from the Mac, the printer gets stuck at 40% after about 5 minutes an error is displayed "unable to verify, printer not responding". When printing from any other Mac or device, printing works.

Is there anything else I can try?

## ATTEMPTS

- rebooting Mac
- rebooting the printer
- resetting the printer to its factory settings
- reset the printing system on the mac
- clearing the queue
- adding the printer by IP address
- installing the HP SMART software
- removing all traces of the HP printer from /Library/Printers, and the Trash

## CONFIRMED

- printer is on the same subnet
- printer can be pinged from the Mac

Comment: Is this a wireless printer?

Comment: @jmh the printer is a wireless printer